# Laravel Mail Class Swift_Message does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email in laravel 5.5. I did everything as in https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail, but I get this error:

> Class Swift_Message does not exist

[image]

I created mailable using

```
 php artisan make:mail OrderShipped
```

and edited the mailable

```
 public function build()
 {
     return $this->from('example@example.com')
            ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
 }
```

anc created nearly empty view

```
 <div>Hi </div>
```

and sending like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Order;
use App\Mail\OrderShipped;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Ship the given order.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $orderId
     * @return Response
     */
    public function ship(Request $request, $orderId)
    {
        $order = Order::findOrFail($orderId);

        // Ship order...

        Mail::to($request->user())->send(new OrderShipped($order));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us how you created your mail instance

Comment: Can you try this: ```Mail::to($request->user()->email)``` although it should work with user object.

Comment: But your user needs to have both a name and an email field.